# Auto drop value everyday

Tags: powershell, designer-workflow, list-form

So I have created a list that has a field that allows a user to input a rating of 1 - 4 which is then linked to another list that totals up each rating for that specific user.

What I need to do is create a workflow that reduces the total by 2 everyday no record is inputted (i.e the figure doesn't increase).

All I can think of is something that sets the workflow off at 2am to check if the total has increased since yesterday if not it will reduce the total by 2 and will keep reducing everyday until it gets to 0.

Is there a setting in the workflow that will allow for this? I'm sure there is something available. 
I don't want to go towards PowerShell as I don't have access to out SharePoint server.

Can anyone help. Please!!!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013 workflow with "Pause 1 day" as the last action and calling itself as the next stage works very consistently. I was skeptical at first that it might have broken at some point, running few test ones for 2-3 months now. Pretty stable I can say.